# Delphi: What's wrong with REST API based on mORMot?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, rest, delphi, webserver

I try to build REST Web Server based on mORMot framework (Delphi) and have issue with getting data from remote DB.

**Server.dpr**

```
const
  CONN_STR =
    'DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;UID=user;PWD=pass;server=server;'
    + 'Trusted_Connection=No;MARS_Connection=yes';
var
  Model: TSQLModel;
  RESTServer: TSQLRestServerDB;
  Application: TwoStreamgateApplication;
  HTTPServer: TSQLHttpServer;
  ODBCConnProp: TSQLDBConnectionPropertiesThreadSafe;
begin
  SQLite3Log.Family.Level := LOG_VERBOSE;
  SQLite3Log.Family.PerThreadLog := ptIdentifiedInOnFile;
  ODBCConnProp := TODBCConnectionProperties.Create('', CONN_STR, 'wo', 'wo');
  try
    ODBCConnProp.ThreadingMode := tmMainConnection;
    Model := CreateModel;
    VirtualTableExternalRegisterAll(Model, ODBCConnProp);
    try
      RESTServer := TSQLRestServerDB.Create(Model, ':memory:');
      try
        RESTServer.DB.Synchronous := smNormal;
        RESTServer.DB.LockingMode := lmExclusive;
        RESTServer.CreateMissingTables;
        Application := TwoStreamgateApplication.Create;
        try
          Application.Start(RESTServer);
          HTTPServer := TSQLHttpServer.Create('8092', [RESTServer]
{$IFNDEF ONLYUSEHTTPSOCKET}, '+', useHttpApiRegisteringURI{$ENDIF});
          try
            HTTPServer.RootRedirectToURI('api/default');
            RESTServer.RootRedirectGet := 'api/default';
            writeln('"MVC WOStreamgate Server" launched on port 8092 using ',
              HTTPServer.HttpServer.ClassName);
            writeln(#10'You can check http://localhost:8092/api/info for information');
            writeln('or point to http://localhost:8092 to access the web app.');
            writeln(#10'Press [Enter] to close the server.'#10);
            readln;
            writeln('HTTP server shutdown...');
          finally
            HTTPServer.Free;
          end;
        finally
          Application.Free;
        end;
      finally
        RESTServer.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Model.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ODBCConnProp.Free;
  end;
```

Model is described below in **ServerModel.pas** unit

```
type
  TSQLBaseData = class(TSQLRecord)
  private
    FName: RawUTF8;
    FDetailURL: RawUTF8;
    FLogoURL: RawUTF8;
    FDescription: RawUTF8;
  published
    property Name: RawUTF8 read FName write FName;
    property Description: RawUTF8 read FDescription write FDescription;
    property LogoURL: RawUTF8 read FLogoURL write FLogoURL;
    property DetailURL: RawUTF8 read FDetailURL write FDetailURL;
  end;

  TSQLStation = class(TSQLBaseData)
  end;

function CreateModel: TSQLModel;

implementation

function CreateModel: TSQLModel;
begin
  result := TSQLModel.Create(
    [TSQLStation],
    'api');
end;
```

View model in **ServerViewModel.pas** unit

```
TServerApplication = class(TMVCApplication, IServerApplication)
  public
    procedure Start(aServer: TSQLRestServer); reintroduce;
    procedure StationView(ID: TID; out Station: TSQLStation);
  end;

implementation 

procedure TServerApplication.Start(aServer: TSQLRestServer);
begin
  inherited Start(aServer,TypeInfo(IServerApplication));
  fMainRunner := TMVCRunOnRestServer.Create(Self).
    SetCache('Default',cacheRootIfNoSession,15);
  aServer.Cache.SetCache(TSQLStation);
end;

procedure TServerApplication.StationView(ID: TID; out Station: TSQLStation);
begin
  RestModel.Retrieve(ID, Station);
end;
```

and now once I type `http://localhost:8092/api/station/10` in browser, I get response

> { "errorCode":404, "errorText":"Not Found" }

in case I type `http://localhost:8092/api/stationview/10` in browser I get rendered page, but without info about `station=10` or any other.

Where did I make a mistake? I want simply get JSON-response to my request

**UPDATE:**

Another info that can help. Once I try the query

```
procedure TestQuery();
var
  SQLDBConnection: TODBCConnection;
  Q: TQuery;
begin
  SQLDBConnection := TODBCConnection.Create(ODBCConnProp);
  Q := TQuery.Create(SQLDBConnection);
  try
    Q.SQL.Clear; // optional
    Q.SQL.Add('select * from dbo.Station');
    Q.Open;
...
```

I catch an error:

> Project Server.exe raised exception class EODBCException with message 'TODBCStatement - TODBCLib
>   error: [HY106] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Fetch type
>   out of range (0) '.

Comment: Do you have a station.ID=10 item in your database? Did you write the mustache view?

Comment: Yes, I have both Station=10 and Mustache View. I see rendered view, but don't see any data fetched from DB

Comment: How was your table created? filled? defined? Is there any exception during SynDB work in the ORM? Sounds like if some column type of an existing DB is not recognized.

Comment: Exception is described above. Tables was created manually by running script.

Comment: How is the table create? I guess the column type is not supported by ODBCSynDB. The best is to let the table be created by the ORM!

Comment: I added to all my DTO classes prefix `2` like `Station2` and run Server again.. nothing happened. Looks like, whether ODBC connection is not good or I configured mORMot Server not well. Please advise me.

Comment: I modified DBConnection from ODBC to ZEOS... and my solution above is working :) Thanks mORMot!  Only one thing I should find out about error `Exception with message 'DBError : [10007] : General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server.
Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.`.` after `http://localhost:8092/api/station/1` request

Comment: With a MS SQL Server, try to use SynOleDB.pas - it is faster and better integrated than ODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple - need to add:

**Database=myDataBase;**

to

> CONN_STR = 'DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;UID=user;PWD=pass;server=server;'
>       + 'Trusted_Connection=No;MARS_Connection=yes';Database=myDataBase;

Thanks Arnaud for great framework!!!